# C# WinForm DataGridView cell clipping region

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, clip

The DataGridView has a column with ComboBoxes. It is necessary to set the clipping area (Cursor.Clip) by the cell from this column when editing it. The algorithm works if CellRect.X = 600, but the clipping coordinates then do not fall on the desired cell. If you increase CellRect.X to 700 and higher, the program behaves as if there is no clipping of the cursor area at all. There is the assumption that the problem is that when you edit the DataGridView cell, a separate cell component is created which is displayed on top of the editable one and with which the EditingControlShowing works. As soon as the cursor enters the coordinates of the new cell, it falls into the area of ​​the new component and the cursor settings of the previous component stop working for it. Maybe anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

```
private void dataGridView3_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{           
   if (DGV_CmbEditing)
   {
    Point PointOnCell = new Point();
    PointOnCell.X = 810;
    PointOnCell.Y = this.Top + e.CellBounds.Y + 10;
    Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(PointOnCell);

    Rectangle CellRect = new Rectangle();
    CellRect.X = 600;
    CellRect.Y = this.Top + e.CellBounds.Y;
    CellRect.Width = e.CellBounds.Width;
    CellRect.Height = e.CellBounds.Height;
    this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
    Cursor.Clip = RectangleToScreen(CellRect);

    DGV_CmbEditing = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: WHY is it … _” … necessary to set the clipping area (Cursor.Clip) by the cell from this column when editing it.”_ ? … why do you need to do this?

Comment: For convenience. The cell has a ComboBox with which you interact with the mouse. It is necessary that when you take the mouse, it does not leave the work area. It's just convenient.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, however I fail see how this would be “convenient” for anyone... I would find this behavior annoying and counter-intuitive. Is this a requested behavior from the user(s)? Have you asked the user(s) if they would like this limited mouse movement behavior? Lastly, when/where is this limited cursor movement turned off? In the current posted code, the cursor will be locked into a small area and the user will not be able to do anything. Can you post a complete [mre] example of the behavior you are looking for and the problem you are having?

Comment: Later it turned out that clipping does not work at all in the entire program and without any conditions. The variation in the first post worked, but did not hit the desired cell. Increasing the X coordinate causes clipping to simply fail. Clipping is turned off by pressing Esc or Enter. There are suspicions that the matter is in the settings of the form.